# Removing nulls while mapping a JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, null

I am developing a Java + Apache Spark application. One of its funcionalities is to trim Strings. For example:

```
// Having JavaSparkContext jsc previously defined and a function like 
// the following already defined:
private String trim(String s, int charsToTrim);
// that returns a new String with length = s.length() - charsToTrim or 
// null if its new length is <= 0

JavaRDD<String> original = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbbb", "ccccc");
int num = 4;
JavaRDD<String> mapped = original.map(s -> trim(s, num));
```

The new JavaRDD mapped will contain (null, null, "c"), and I will have to clean null values with a filter.

The question I have is: Is there any way to remove those values while doing the map or to don't return any value at while mapping all if the result is null?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove or filter some values you can always use `.filter` over an RDD.

But you can not use `.map` for skipping the elements or filtering them. However, you can use `flatMap` method here which supports the intended functionality. Try the following line in your code:

```
mapped.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList((x == null)? (new String[0]) : (new String[]{x})).iterator());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that gave me the hint I needed!